# Typeorm select+update works in incorrect order

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I use typeorm with postgresql and nestjs. As part of one request I do the following steps:

1. Select top records from TABLE1 using this.createQueryBuilder('TABLE1')..andWhere('status = :status', { status }).getMany();
2. Then update each of  selected records with new status this.update(id,data);
3. Repeat step 1 with the same query (suppose to have another records as status of previosly selected records was updated)
4. Repeat step 2 (update records selected in step 3)

The issue is that even though I do 2 selects that suppose to to return different records both selects return the same records so I do update on the same set twice. According to logs it looks like typeorm (or postgres?) executes two selects first (1 and 3) and aftet that make 2 updates (2 and 4).

I added cache(false) to the selects but it didn't help.

How can I make queries to be executed in the correct order?

Comment: please add an example code that is trying to execute what you have described